# How to create multiple group input type in single form in angular js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using angula js and php in project
I want to create a form there is multiple input type that is group wise in single form like

name email phone
name email phone
name email phone
name email phone
name email phone

there is not a certain group it can be 10 to 50 so i want to create it in loop
1: How to create in loop
2: How to upload on server

Please help me Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use 'ng-repeat' on `$scope` :

```
<input  ng-model="numberOfInputs" type="text"/>
<button ng-click="myFunc()"> set number of inputs! </button>

<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input ng-model="item.name" type="text" />
    <input ng-model="item.phone" type="text" />
</div>
```

**in your controller:**

suppose we can set number of inputs and we store it 
in $scope.numberOfInputs :

```
$scope.items = [];

$scope.myFunc = function(){

    for (i = 0; i < $scope.numberOfInputs.length; i++) { 

         $scope.items.push({id:i,name:'', email:''});
    }

}
```

then `$scope.items` could be send with angular `$http` service to php! 
 and then for converting it to array use `json-decode()` . after that use php's 
`foreach` loop to iterate trough this array and save each one separatly!

Comment: How to create $scope.items json array in loop i have not a fix value of input group it will be change time to time

Comment: my form in modal so i am calling a function $scope.addAttendance = function(item){} I have called above function myFunc within this function when i am calling this function I am getting undefined function

Comment: I have solved my above issue now function is calling

Comment: Yes Thank you :) One last question after submitting form how to save in database separately input group

Comment: ng-repeat="item in items" (ng-model="item.name") there is multiple ng-model="item.name[$index]" so i have did this after submitting a form i am getting blank object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110119/discussion-between-mishraoft-and-ahmad-mobaraki).